# How can I reduce the size of my .ai file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs4

I've designed a catalog, using Illustrator CS4 and I have placed high resolution images into the document, which now has a file size of 1 GB.  How can I reduce this file size to 20-30 MB?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to reduce the size of your .ai file or the files (.pdf, .png, etc.) that you export from that file?  Are your images PLACED in the document or did you open them in new documents and drag them in?

Comment: I want to convert the ".AI" file, I have drag images in illustrator

Comment: Convert it to what?

Comment: To Illustrator file

Comment: A lot of people downvoted this and I assume it's because of the poor English?  Maybe it's a duplicate?  I don't know, I don't think it's a bad question at all.  A lot of people make this mistake, when first learning AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, instead of dragging images into your .ai file, is to place (link) the images into the document.

FILE > PLACE

[image: place]

Make sure that "Link" is checked

[image: link]

Now your linked image is in your document

[image]

If you need to edit or update your links, go to WINDOW > LINKS

[image: links]

****IMPORTANT**** Using this method means that you must also send along any images that you have linked to the printer.  What I recommend doing is having an "images" or "links" folder inside your main document folder (see below).  I suggest that you place all of your images into your image folder **BEFORE** you link them.  That way, your links will already be correct when you make them.

[image: folder]

It's worth noting, however, that if you are sending a PDF to be printed, you don't need to worry about sending the images, as the PDF will have the images embedded within itself.